# How can I make my turtle move to my cursor?

Tags: python, onclick, turtle-graphics

I am trying to move the turtle to my cursor to draw something so that every time I click, the turtle will go there and draw something.

I have already tried onscreenclick(), onclick, and many combinations of both, I feel like I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

```
from turtle import*
import random
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed(0)
col  = ["red","green","blue","orange","purple","pink","yellow"]
a = random.randint(0,4)
siz = random.randint(100,300)
def draw():
    for i in range(75):
        turtle.color(col[a])
        turtle.forward(siz)
        turtle.left(175)

TurtleScreen.onclick(turtle.goto)
```

Any help would be great, thank you for your time ( If you help me! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so much what method you're invoking, but on what object you're invoking it:

```
TurtleScreen.onclick(turtle.goto)
```

`TurtleScreen` is a class, you need to call it on a screen instance.  And since you want to call `draw` in addition to `turtle.goto` you need to define your own function that calls both:

```
screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(my_event_handler)
```

Here's a rework of your code with the above fixes and other tweaks:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop
from random import choice, randint

COLORS = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "pink", "yellow"]

def draw():
    size = randint(100, 300)

    # make turtle position center of drawing
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() - size/2)

    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(75):
        turtle.color(choice(COLORS))
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(175)

    turtle.penup()

def event_handler(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)  # disable event handler inside event handler

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    draw()

    screen.onclick(event_handler)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(event_handler)

mainloop()
```

Comment: I accidentally missed this.